# Python Twitter streaming & Sentiment analysis by tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I'm beginner in python. I have a code that takes data from twitter by tweepy and print it in "real time". I would like to do a sentiment analysis of tweets.
How can I process this data to clean the text and get the subjectivity, polarity using textblob, wordcloud?

```
class StreamCollector(tweepy.Stream):

     def on_data(self, data):
        import json

        tweet_info = json.loads(data)
        print(tweet_info['text'])

stream = StreamCollector(
    "key1", "key2",
    "key3", "key4"
)

stream.filter(track=["text"])
```

Comment: first find some tutorial to learn how to use modules for `sentiment-analysis` because this is too broad problem for Stackoverflow

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.